# How can i delete firebase child node with the same name?Get the key to be delited from one node and delete those node with same key from the other

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete all the child nodes form different nodes with the same names. I used the following code to get the keys of the child nodes to be deleted and pass it to the other node but it is deleting them from both nodes(`completedSurveys` and `surveyList`).

```
DatabaseReference dr_completedSurveys = firebaseDatabase.getReference("users").child(userId).child("completedSurveys");
    dr_completedSurveys.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                stringBuilder.append(ds.getKey()).append("\n");
                String completedSurveys = stringBuilder.toString();
                String[] lines = completedSurveys.split("\n");
                for (String line : lines) {
                    //Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String compSurList = line;
                    DatabaseReference dr_completed = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(userId);
                    dr_completed.child("surveyList").child(compSurList).removeValue();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image]

Attached below is the firebase realtime database structure.

Comment: What is the exact name of the node you want to delete? Provide us an example.

Comment: @AlexMamo sld0000001 and sId0000002 are the ones that i want to delete from surveyList node. I want the child nodes which will be copied from surveyList upon complications to completedSurveys to be deleted from surveyList

Comment: So you only want sld0000001 and sId0000002 to be deleted from `surveyList` node, right? Do you have those values in an array or a list? Would like to be deleted all at once or one by one?

Comment: It could be deleted one by one or once;i just want to delete all the names which are found on both db from surveyList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It could be deleted one by one or once; I just want to delete all the names which are found on both DB from `surveyList`.

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference completedSurveysRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid).child("completedSurveys");
```

Now to remove all values within the `completedSurveys` node at once, you should use the following line of code:

```
completedSurveysRef.removeValue();
```

If you want to delete each child separately, please use the following lines of code:

```
completedSurveysRef.child("sld0000001").removeValue();
completedSurveysRef.child("sld0000002").removeValue();
```

**Edit:**

According to your comment:

> Dear Alex, I want to remove all child nodes from `surveyList`, that are in completedList. sld0000001 and sld0000002 are both in `completedList` and surveyList, so I want to remove these values from `surveyList` not from `comletedList`.

Please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference completedSurveysRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid).child("completedSurveys");
DatabaseReference surveyListRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid).child("surveyList");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String surveyId = ds.getKey();;
            surveyListRef.child(surveyId).removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
completedSurveysRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Dear Alex,I want to remove all child node from surveyList,that are in completedList. sld0000001 and sld0000002 are both in completedList and surveyList,so i want to remove these values from surveyList not from comletedList.

Comment: Ok, now I understood exactly. I'll update the answer in a moment.

Comment: Please check my updated answer and tell me if it works.

Comment: The modified code is deleting the child node from both completedSurveys and surveyList. It is the same as the one i posted in the begening. Is there any other way to pass [String surveyId = ds.getKey();] as a string from onDataChange() method.

Comment: The code that I have added deletes only the items in `surveyList`, as you requested. There is **NO** way it deletes items from `completedSurveys`, unless you explicitly specified that in your code. Edit your question with the changed code.

Comment: Hi Alex Mamo, it is still not working. The code is deleting from both surveyList and completedList.

Comment: There is no way it can happen that. Please edit your question with the changed code, to see it more clearly.

Comment: i already have a screen record,if there is a way to post it i would

Comment: There is no need for a screen record, simply edit your question and add the code that produces that behavior.

Comment: Hi Alex, i actually get an answer from your another post on kind of similar scenario, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774   Thanks!